# In ojdbc6, what does unmarshalCLR and unmarshalUB1 do?

Tags: java, jdbc, ojdbc

In ojdbc6, an accessor can call the `oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine`'s `unmarshalCLR` method during unmarshaling of results from a database. Inside `unmarshalCLR`, there is also this `unmashalUB1` method.

What do these two methods do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an Oracle database specific thing relating to their TNS protocol.

A google search turns up [a spec](http://www.pythian.com/blog/repost-oracle-protocol/), though I have no idea how accurate or up-to-date it is.

Mentioning CLRs:

> A CLR is a byte array in 64-byte blocks. If its length <=64, it is just
>   length-byte-preceeded and written as native. Null arrays can be written as the
>   single bytes 0x0 or 0xff. If length >64, first a LNG byte (0xfe) is written,
>   then the array is written in length-byte-preceeded chunks of 64 bytes (although
>   the final chunk can be shorter), followed by a 0 byte. A chunk preceeded by a
>   length of 0xfe is ignored.

Looks like a CLR is an encoded byte array.

A UB1 is simply an unsigned byte (data type length of 1 byte).